# Making div table cells responsive and rearanaged

Tags: html, css

I am trying to make this website design responsive. I want it so that when it gets to mobile view, that the cells collapse to be on top of each other. Most importantly I want box5 to be the box on top.

I have built this media query....The problem is, that it seems to change the positions of my boxes before the query is triggered (It seems to revert them back to the original way they are when the query triggers..(this is the exact opposite of what I want)...Also, when it collapses into lots of rows, it doesn't apply the height and they're too small.

```
@media (min-width: 768px) {

  html,body,.main { height: 100%; }
  div {
    position: absolute;
  }
  .box1,
  .box2,
  .box5 {
    top: 0;
    bottom: 66.6666%;
  }
  .box3,
  .box4,
  .box6 {
    top: 33.3333%;
    bottom: 33.3333%;
  }
  .box7,
  .box8,
  .box9 {
    top: 66.6666%;
    bottom: 0;
  }
  .box5,
  .box3,
  .box7 {
    left: 0;
    right: 66.6666%
  }
  .box1,
  .box6,
  .box9{
    right: 0;
    left: 66.6666%
  }
  .box2,
  .box4,
  .box8 {
    left: 33.3333%;
    right: 33.3333%;
  }
        .box1, .box2, .box3, .box4, .box5, .box6, .box7, .box8, .box9 {
         height:150px;
    }
}
```

Here is my codepen so you can understand what's going on...http://codepen.io/pisoj1/pen/BQWyRr

Answer (score 0):

**Update:**

**Snippet updated**

Now I understand what you're trying to do. You can do this by adding a duplicate `box5` element and setting it to `display:none` and then changing the display property in a `@media Rule`

Any screen smaller than 600px wide will show `box5` at the top. **You change that to your target screen.**

That's *Unless* **you have to do this on many pages** and for many elements, *then you might want to look at something beyond* `css`

---

**Old Answer**

**This an overly simplified layout** and you **won't** need `@Media queries`

However, *I think* it **produces** the desired **effect**.

**Wrap** your smaller boxes in a container `<div>`

*Open the snippet in fullscreen* then **resize the window** to see how the **boxes stack.**

```css
.container: {
  margin: 2% auto;
}
.box {
  margin: 3%;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  display: inline-block
}


/* ------------------------------- Start Effect CSS --------------------------------------- */


#b5a {
  /* I add a duplicate element that is set to display:none by defualt.  it will only show up if the screen is smaller that "x" value. */
  display: none
}
@media (max-width: 600px) {
  /* Here you can Change resolution below which box5 will be on top - "x" value */
  #b5a {
    display: inline-block
  }
  #b5b {
    display: none
  }
}

/* ------------------------------- End Effect CSS --------------------------------------- */


/* ------------------------------ Start misc CSS selectors ------------------------------ */

body {
  background: #131418;
  color: #999;
  text-shadow: 2px 2px 10px #000;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 2em
}
#b1 {
  background: red
}
#b2 {
  background: blue
}
#b3 {
  background: green
}
#b4 {
  background: yellow
}
#b5a,
#b5b {
  background: orange
}
#b6 {
  background: teal
}
#b7 {
  background: cyan
}
#b8 {
  background: purple
}
.visual {
  border: 1px solid #444;
  box-shadow: inset 0px 0px 200px 50px rgba(0, 0, 0, .7)
}
/* ------------------------------ End misc CSS selectors ------------------------------ */
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="box visual" id="b5a">5</div>
  <div class="box visual" id="b1">1</div>
  <div class="box visual" id="b2">2</div>
  <div class="box visual" id="b3">3</div>
  <div class="box visual" id="b4">4</div>
  <div class="box visual" id="b5b">5</div>
  <div class="box visual" id="b6">6</div>
  <div class="box visual" id="b7">7</div>
  <div class="box visual" id="b8">8</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Not what I'm after. See box5 before being responsive is in the middle of the cells so it would be cell #5....but when it goes to responsive I want it to be cell #1

Comment: I updated the answer, let me know if that does the job

Comment: Sort of...but I think I've figured out a more elegant way.

Comment: Great! I am glad you've figured it out. If possible, do share your method of doing it as an answer - you can even mark it as the correct answer if nobody suggests a better method and your happy with it - Posting it here means others will benefit from it at a later date.

Comment: Will do when I get it going.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to solve it. I understood that, I made my mobile view the default view and then when it's above 768px wide, I go to the desktop view and change the positions. So I made my box1 store my middle image (box5) so it was an easy swap...As for the height issue,  I made it change the height of my boxes when the width is a MAX of 769px.

```
@media(min-width:768px){
  html,body,main{
    height: 100%;
  }
  div{
    position: absolute;
  }
  .box5,
  .box2,
  .box3{
    top:0;
    bottom:66.6666%
  }
  .box4,
  .box1,
  .box6{
    top:33.3333%;
    bottom:33.3333%;
  }
  .box7,
  .box8,
  .box9{
    top:66.6666%;
    bottom:0;
  }
  .box2,
  .box4,
  .box7{
    left:0;
    right:66.6666%
  }
  .box3,
  .box6,
  .box9{
    right:0;
    left:66.6666%
  }
  .box5,
  .box1,
  .box8{
    left:33.3333%;
    right:33.3333%;
  }

}
@media(max-width:768px){
        .box1, .box2, .box3, .box4, .box5, .box6, .box7, .box8, .box9 {
         height:150px;
    }

}
```